# Python InstaBot, if posts are already liked, I wannna skipped the post

Tags: python, automated-tests, instagram

I made the code for insta in Python for my learning. This code already works but sometimes it repeats like and like cancel one post many times without jumping to the next post. So I would like to add code that skips any posts if it already liked.
I would really appraciate if you could give me some advice.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
import random


def login():
    driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?source=auth_switcher')
    f = open('insta.txt','a')
    f.write("instagram access\n")
    f.close()
    time.sleep(1)
    
    driver.find_element_by_name('username').send_keys('')
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys('')
    time.sleep(1)
    
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('L3NKy       ').click()
    time.sleep(random.randint(2, 5))
    f = open('insta.txt','a')
    f.write("instagram log in\n")
    f.close()
    time.sleep(1)

def tagsearch(tag):
    instaurl = 'https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/'
    driver.get(instaurl + tag)
    time.sleep(random.randint(2, 10))
    f = open('insta.txt','a')
    f.write("listtag tag search\n")
    f.close()
    time.sleep(1)

def clicknice():
    target = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('_9AhH0')[10]
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.move_to_element(target)
    actions.perform()
    f = open('insta.txt','a')
    f.write("move new post\n")
    f.close()
    time.sleep(1)
    
    try:
        driver.find_elements_by_class_name('_9AhH0')[9].click()
        time.sleep(random.randint(2, 10))
        f = open('insta.txt','a')
        f.write("post click\n")
        f.close()
        time.sleep(1)
        driver.find_element_by_class_name('fr66n').click()
        f = open('insta.txt','a')
        f.write("post liked\n")
        f.close()
        time.sleep(3)
    
    except WebDriverException:
        f = open('insta.txt','a')
        f.write("error occured\n")
        f.close()
        return

    for i in range(random.randint(3, 5)):
        
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[6]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/button').click()
            f = open('insta.txt','a')
            f.write("move next post\n")
            f.close()
            time.sleep(random.randint(random.randint(3, 5), random.randint(10, 14)))

        except WebDriverException:
            f = open('insta.txt','a')
            f.write("error occured2\n")
            f.close()
            time.sleep(5)

        try:
            driver.find_element_by_class_name('fr66n').click()
            f = open('insta.txt','a')
            f.write("liked post\n")
            f.close()
            time.sleep(2)
            
        except WebDriverException:
            f = open('insta.txt','a')
            f.write("error occured3\n")
            f.close()

          
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    taglist = ['']
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = '')
    time.sleep(1)
    login()
    
    while True:
        tagsearch(random.choice(taglist))
        clicknice()
        
        abc = random.randint(random.randint(4200, 4400), random.randint(4700, 4900))
        f = open('insta.txt','a')
        f.write(str(abc)+"seconds wait\n")
        f.close()
        time.sleep(abc)
```